# jQuery Selecting children for hover function NO TAG

Tags: jquery, dom, children

I have a question regarding how to set a hover function for my custom back to top button. I am  translating my website with translate.js which means I very often require live manipulation of the DOM, and such is the case with this problem.
I can do this with CSS but am interested in jQuery due to my will of expanding the functionality and animation further. I have a back to top button that looks like this:

[image: backtotop]

```
<a id='backtotop-button' href='#top' class='hvr-grow-rotate footerLink trn'>
</a>
```

I then have a function that sets the correct text depending on language and appends a little arrow of back to top.

```
$('#backtotop-button').empty();
$('#backtotop-button').append(
    `${translator.get('Back to Top ')} <i id='footerLinks6' class='fa fa-arrow-up'></i>`
);
```

My problem comes when selecting this text that is within no tag, as well as the arrow....

My hover function:

```
$('#backtotop-button').children().hover(function() {
        $(this).css('background-color', '#33A2FB');
}, function() {
        $(this).css('background-color', '#FFF');
});
```

I want to make the text and arrow change to blue on hover basically, but I am getting the whole link area (a square) in blue,

Comment: testable example in jjba.ddnsking.com

Comment: It is not clear what is your current problem, can you share with us more information?